# How do I mock creating a connection to HBase in a constructor?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, hbase, mockito, powermock

I am trying to set up my unit tests so that I can test my HBase Client. However, I am having trouble mocking the creation of the connection to HBase in the constructor. I don't think I am correctly injecting the mocked connection into the class I want to test, but I'm not sure where I made the mistake. I've looked at similar questions about mocking a connection, but all of those have the creation of the connection outside of the constructor.

This is the code I am trying to test:

```
@Lazy
@Service("HBaseClient") 
public class HBaseClient {

    /**
     * Instantiate a new client and create connection to HBase.
     */
    public HBaseClient() {
        // Create connection to HBase
        conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        conf.setInt("timeout", 120000);
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", zookeeperHost);
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", zookeeperPort);
        conf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", znodeParent);
        try {
            connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error creating connection to HBase - IOException");
        }
    }

public void addRecord(String rowKey, String columnFamily, Map<String, String> values) {
...
```

Here is what I have in the unit test:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class TestHBaseClient {

    @InjectMocks
    private static HBaseClient hbaseClient;

    @BeforeClass
    @PrepareForTest({ConnectionFactory.class})
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        Connection mockConnection = PowerMockito.mock(Connection.class);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ConnectionFactory.class);
        PowerMockito.when(ConnectionFactory.createConnection()).thenReturn(mockConnection);
        hbaseClient = new HBaseClient();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddRecord() {
        HashMap<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>();
        values.put("test1", "abc");
        values.put("test2", "xyz");
        hbaseClient.addRecord("test", "Test", values);
    }
}
```

The code as it currently is throws the following error:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
>   when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
>   For example:
>       when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
>
> Also, this error might show up because:
>   1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.    Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
>   2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
>   3. the parent of the mocked class is not public.    It is a limitation of the mock engine.
>
> at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when(PowerMockito.java:495)
>     at
>   com.rtn.cdp.storage.hbase.test.TestHBaseDataClient.setUpBeforeClass(TestHBaseClient.java:32)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runBefores(ClassRoadie.java:56)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:43)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:118)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:101)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Comment: In your code you have `ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf)`. But when mocking you are mocking `ConnectionFactory.createConnection()` without any argument.

Comment: @pvpkiran Thank you! That looks like it might be the source of the problem. Since I don't want to mock the creation of the configuration, what is the best way to tell PowerMock that I am passing it in?

Comment: `PowerMockito.when(ConnectionFactory.createConnection(any(Configuration.class))).thenReturn(mockConnection);`

Comment: @pvpkiran `PowerMockito.when(ConnectionFactory.createConnection(any(HBaseConfiguration.class))).thenReturn(mockConnection);` throws a null pointer exception.

Comment: NPE where. you should try debugging